# Thymeleaf: Partially set values to model object from outside the form tags

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have an model object that I send to front end. I populate that object inside the form. What I want to know is that if I can partially populate that object from a different event before user submits his/her form?

Example:

Entity:

```
public class Participant {
  public String username;
  public boolean taskCompleted;
}
```

Thymeleaf Form:

```
<form th:object="${participant}" th:action="@{/join}" method="post">
  <input type="text" th:field="*{username}" >
  <button type="submit">Join!</button>
</form>
```

Before submitting the form, I give users a task, like clicking a button on a different part of the page. If they do it, I want to do something like `taskCompleted = true` of the same `participant` object. Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a hidden input in your form:

```
<form th:object="${participant}" method="post">
  <input type="text" th:field="*{username}" >
  <input type="hidden" th:field="*{taskCompleted}" />
  <button type="submit">Join!</button>
</form>
```

When the user clicks a button, use JavaScript to set the value of the hidden `input` to true.

```
<!-- This button flips the value of taskCompleted to true -->
<button onclick="document.getElementById('taskCompleted').value = 'true';">Do the task first!</button>
```

Comment: Can you show me an example how to set hidden value with javascript?

Comment: @gozluklu_marti -- added an example `<button />`. (And change the hidden field to use `th:field`... instead of `th:value`.

Comment: It's working, thank you! I just had to add `id="taskCompleted"` into hidden input tag.